# Loading a ViewController from nib file owner

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode10, swift4.2

I have a design made in nib and in round about all ViewControllers I am loading that nib design.

Now as that was common footer so I managed to used it in the footer of all other view controllers.

**Now what I want** : I want that whenever User click on a footer it must start a new View Controller that will show what you can say "About us " view controller.

**What I am doing:**

```
// ON CLICK OF FOOTER I AM DOING 
 let mAboutUs = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idAboutUs") as! AboutUs
    mAboutUs.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(mAboutUs, animated: true) {

    }
```

but I am getting following error

> **Value of type 'FooterView' has no member 'storyboard'**

**My Understanding:** I think from nib file we can not start a new ViewController, But I really do not want to do this thing in all other View controllers in which I added this nib (FooterView) as my footer view at bottom of each view controller.

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIView` subclass doesn't contain a `storyboard` property it's for a vc subclass , You need

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idAboutUs") as! AboutUs
```

if you want to present a vc from inisde the view `FooterView` then add a delegate like

```
weak var delegate:VCName?
```

When you create an instance

```
let ins = FooterView() // or from storyboard 
ins.delegate = self
```

Then use

```
delegate?.present(mAboutUs, animated: true)
```

inside the view's class

---

You can use a delegate that all vcs conforms to but the easiest is to add this extension

```
extension UIViewController {
    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {

        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            return presented.topMostViewController()
        }

        if let navigation = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigation.visibleViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? navigation
        }

        if let tab = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tab.selectedViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? tab
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Then

```
 guard let currentVC =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController.topMostViewController() else { return } 
 currentVC.present(mAboutUs, animated: true)
```

Comment: and what If I want to present it modally?

Comment: dude i did not get it, I just want to show it modally above  previous View Controller

Comment: I am not creating any Instance of CustomView, I am just adding that using Storyboard

Comment: `FooterView` = `CustomView`

Comment: i got you by footerView = customview, but I am adding that using storyboard, not programmatically

Comment: whatever the creation,  add the delegate var and set it

Comment: what is vcName ?

Comment: it's the vc name that holds the footerView

Comment: there are more then 21 View Controller , what name should I use

Comment: I did not get what you  are saying since there is no clear instruction how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look similar to this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "<Name of the storyboard that contains the About Us VC>", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idAboutUs") as! AboutUs

self.present(vc, animated: true) {

    }
```

Comment: but self.present got error as present is not a method provided in nib file

Comment: you can call it in a viewController like this: self.present(<#T##viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>, completion: <#T##(() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>)

Comment: I dont have view controller, I have a nib file

Comment: So it's a view maybe, then you can send the action from the footer to the VC that encapsulates it. From there you can run this code

Comment: so it means i have to work that in all view controllers.

Comment: yep, the present method is only in the UIViewControllers. After that when you want to dismiss it, you can use: self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {}

Comment: @A.s.ALI I think your problem is you are not finding a presenter to present your view controller created. 
You can make it simple. Create a helper method an extension to `UIViewController` that will return `topPresentedViewController` and you can call that from anywhere in the app.

Something like that `class var topPresentedViewController : UIViewController { //code to get top presented view controller you can find from stack overflow}`

Then you can call it from anywhere footer etc. 
And present your view as `UIViewController.topPresentedViewController.present(view, animated: true)`